# Fuso Horário Brasileiro no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela do banco de dados MySQL chamada `registros`.

Nela, eu tenho então a seguinte estrutura:
`id_registro`, `nome_registro`, `data_registro`.

Em `data_registro` eu estou usando o current_timestamp(), buscando a hora do servidor na hora de adicionar. A questão é: Esta hora não é a mesma do Brasil, por estar num servidor dos EUA.

Como eu faço para que ao adicionar no banco de dados, faça a inserção da hora brasileira? (4 hs de diferença).

Comment: Mostre o que vc tentou fazer...

Comment: Não tenho nada, porque o horário do sistema está correto, se eu der echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s") funciona normal, mas minha duvida é sobre o SQL mesmo, como eu faria? Queria alterar algo dentro do php admin ou do php.ini que fizesse então essa alteração automaticamente, que eu não precisasse manipular os dados na hora de inserir.

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor essa para *buscando a hora do servidor na hora de adicionar. A questão é: Esta hora não é a mesma do Brasil, por estar num servidor dos EUA*

Comment: data_registro poderia ser utilizado now(), por exemplo.

Comment: É que na hora de inserir, eu passo o campo vazio, pra que ele insira o current_timestamp() do mysql já

Comment: O mysql não sabe o fuso daqui, então ele coloca a hora diferente

Comment: E como eu manipulo isso?

Comment: **SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 3 hour** coloque isso

Comment: Onde eu colocaria? Não entendi bem..

Comment: aonde vc deixa em banco, coloque isso

Comment: Estranho você falar em "hora do Brasil", o Brasil tem faixas do território com 4 diferentes fusos horários: UTC - 5 horas, UTC - 4 horas, UTC - 3 horas (horário de Brasília), UTC - 2 horas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Altere a variável global de fuso horário:

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+3:00';
QUIT
```

[A variável time_zone](https://elias.praciano.com/2015/07/como-ajustar-o-fuso-horario-ou-timezone-no-mysql/) pode ser ajustada direto no console do cliente MySQL.
Verifique a sua hora atual com a função NOW(), antes de começar a brincar:

```
SELECT NOW();
```

Em seguida, altere a variável global de fuso horário e desconecte do servidor:

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+3:00';
QUIT
```

Você precisa sair e entrar de novo na sua sessão MySQL para poder ver os efeitos.
Assim que reiniciar a sessão do MySQL, verifique novamente a hora atual:

SELECT NOW();

Se você tiver o banco de dados de nomes de zonas de fusos horários adequadamente configurado, pode se referir às zonas pelos seus nomes. Veja um exemplo:

```
SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo';

SELECT @@time_zone;
```

Para poder se referir a um nome de zona de fuso horário, como ‘Brazil/DeNoronha’, você precisa estar com o banco de dados de nomes de timezones corretamente configurado. Se você tiver dúvidas sobre este assunto, ou não estiver conseguindo usar os nomes das zonas de fusos, [leia este artigo](http://elias.praciano.com/2015/07/como-configurar-o-fuso-horario-do-mysql-por-nomes/).
Para ver todos os fusos válidos para o Brazil, por exemplo, use a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_name WHERE Name LIKE '%Brazil%';
```

Veja mais detalhes [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069310/2740371).

Comment: Pra eu fazer isto, preciso de acesso super global né? acesso root

Comment: [Sim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19881949/2740371)

Comment: @AndréBaill Mas se o cliente não tem tal privilégio, como faz?

Comment: Ai acho que tem que pedir para executar este comando no servidor.. penso eu.. @TalesBreno

Answer (score 1):

Adicione `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');` no inicio do seu código PHP, assim o `timezone` ficará corretamente configurado. Lembrando que você tem que adicionar na página que faz o `insert` no MySQL.

Comment: Isso alterar no PHP a data?

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 não.. isso você coloca no arquivo .php que tem o INSERT INTO tabela... Esse código você adiciona no arquivo PHP mesmo

Comment: Legal, não sabia que dava para fazer dessa forma também, +1