# Como inserir dados no banco Msqli usando data atual

Tags: php, mysql

Como eu consigo inserir os dados no banco usando a *data atual do Brasil* e não a hora dos *EUA*?

**Código:**

```
     $result_cad_user = "INSERT INTO adms_usuarios (nome, email, usuario, senha, $campo_foto adms_niveis_acesso_id, adms_sits_usuario_id, created  ) VALUES (
    '" . $dados_validos['nome'] . "',
    '" . $dados_validos['email'] . "',
    '" . $dados_validos['usuario'] . "',
    '" . $dados_validos['senha'] . "',
    $valor_foto
    '" . $dados_validos['adms_niveis_acesso_id'] . "',
    '" . $dados_validos['adms_sits_usuario_id'] . "',
    NOW())";
```

Comment: Resposta da questão em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151716/fuso-hor%C3%A1rio-brasileiro-no-mysql e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql/19069310#19069310

Comment: eu li porem não resolveu meu problema ela continua inserindo com +4 horas :(

Comment: ele explica como fazer isso com configurações no  "my.cnf" e eu não vou ter acesso por exemplo se eu usar um servidor compartilhado, no servidor local até consigo mais tem que funcoinar em ambos.

Comment: @WesleyRoberto, quando se conectar ao banco de dados, basta executar a *query* `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-3:00';` ou `SET time_zone = '-3:00';`

Comment: eu li sobre isso mais eu uso no meu arquivo de conexão? não entendi direito, serve para inserção de novos dados? tem algum exemplo de como eu insiro esta linha que tu passou , por favor.

Comment: Isso é pra mudar no servidor né?

Answer (score 1):

Oi, eu insiro a data de criação em minhas tabelas da seguinte forma:

```
.date('Y-m-d').
```

E quando eu quero exibir a data eu uso:

```
   $data_formatada = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data_cadastro));
```

// Modifica a zona de tempo a ser utilizada. Disnovível desde o PHP 5.1

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Você pode entender melhor [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)

Comment: O meu problemas esta no registro de novos usuários, quando eu vou inseri-los eles sempre são inseridos com +4 horas e eu quero que ele insira no horario brasileiro (SP)  ou seja -4 horas que o servidor . Será que consegue me ajudar?

Comment: @WesleyRoberto editei minha resposta da uma olhada vê se te ajuda, se não eu tento algo aqui.

Comment: eu não consegui com esses  date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 
só pra saber se estou certo eu utilizo no inicio do codigo responsavel por processar os dados para o banco de dados não é?

Comment: no começo do seu código use isso aqui <?php  
echo date_default_timezone_get();;
?>
pra gente ver qual zona ele ta pegando

Comment: consegui usando $conn->query("SET time_zone = '-03:00';"); e date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');  
Muito obrigado, uma outra coisa na hora exibir ele está exibindo assim: 0 dias, 0 horas, 2 minutos, tem como eu ocutar os minutos depois  que completar 59 e exibir só as horas  ?

Answer (score 1):

O que você precisa fazer é atualizar a configuração de *timezone[1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)* do *MySQL*. Dessa forma você poderá e terá o horário conforme o país/região que desejar. Abaixo mostro algumas formas.

#### Alterar durante a conexão

**MySQLi:**

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if ($conn->connect_error) die ("Check error");

$conn->query("SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-03:00';");
/* ou */
$conn->query("SET time_zone = '-03:00';");
```

**PDO:**

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost', 'user', 'password');

$conn->query("SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-03:00';");
/* ou */
$conn->query("SET time_zone = '-03:00';");
```

#### Arquivo *my.cnf*:

Neste arquivo, você poderá utilizar a configuração abaixo

```
default-time-zone='-03:00'
```

---

#### No *PHP*:

Uma alternativa é utilizar o *PHP* para converter as datas. Há algumas opções como: `timezone` e `DateTime`, por exemplo.

**Exemplo com *DateTime*:**

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));

$conn->query("INSERT INTO table (`name`, `date`) VALUES ('Nome', '{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}') ");
```

<sup>**Exemplo: https://ideone.com/IicXqf**</sup>

**Exemplo com *date_default_timezone_set*:**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$conn->query("INSERT INTO table (`name`, `date`) VALUES ('Nome', '{$date}') ");
```

<sup>**Exemplo: https://ideone.com/PTC2Lx**</sup>

Comment: Eu acho melhor carregar os [timezone tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html) e usar o timezone `America/Sao_Paulo`. Se usar um valor fixo como -03:00, terá que mudar novamente no horário de verão (pois durante o horário de verão passa a ser -02:00), e quando acaba o horário de verão, mudar novamente para -03:00. Já usando `America/Sao_Paulo` (e com os timezone tables configurados), essas mudanças são [gerenciadas automaticamente](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/the-proper-way-to-handle-multiple-time-zones-in-mysql)

Comment: @hkotsubo, verdade, assim como ele também poderia utilizar a opção `--timezone` ao iniciar o serviço. Porém o usuário pode não ter acesso ao utilizar um servidor compartilhado, segundo comentário dele https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/364417/como-inserir-dados-no-banco-msqli-usando-data-atual/364442#comment727464_364417

Comment: tem alguma outra forma de fazer isso ??se tiver me ajuda.. valeu

Comment: @WesleyRoberto Isso o quê?